# WP7 In-App purchase

Tags: windows-phone-7, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Could you tell me how I can integrate In-App to Windows Phone **7**.
I know that with Windows Phone 8 this feature is native. But we need implement it to WP7 too.

Service should provide opportunity to pay via Card (Master, Visa), SMS, or something else.

I know about Linxter, but it's private beta and developers don't respond to us. 
Maybe other services exists?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I Know you cannot integrate IAP (In App Purchases) in Windows Phone 7 as its dependent on some libraries that are not available for Windows Phone 7 Mango(7.5) and its only exclusively available for Windows Phone 8.

But You can do two things.

1. If your app is compiled with Windows Phone 7.5 and if its runs on Windows Phone 8 Devices then we can put IAP through reflection method. So If Your Windows Phone 7.5 Compiled app runs on 7.5 firmware devices then there will be no IAP but if the same app runs on 8.0 firmware devices then it will implement IAP.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside+Windows+Phone/Inside-Windows-Phone-45--Adding-In-App-Purchase-as-a-light-up-feature-to-your-Windows-Phone-7-Games

1. You can use any payment gateway and integrate into your web and once user clicks for Payments then you should open that payment page in webbrowser task and web will be communicated through secure Connection "HTTPS".

I hope it will helps you :)

Comment: I neve rgot this storewapper to work properly. It shows correct AppId and all but always returns zero product. When testing on WP8 app, using same AppId, product magically appears. Any pointers?